# numpy extract xyz points from 3 lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 lists

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Now I would like to extract the points. So that the final array would look like :

```
points = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2] ... ]
```

Is there an easy way to do it using numpy, than using the for loop?

Comment: [`np.column_stack([x, y, z])`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks, you can post this as an answer, if you want. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip and list:

```
points = list(zip(x,y,z))
```

You can also transpose a numpy array:

```
points = np.array([x,y,z]).T
```

And, you can stack them on dimensions you choose:

```
points = np.stack([x,y,z], 1)
```